# raii architecture using c++ and glfw

Tags: c++, glfw, raii, exception-safety, c++17

I'm currently attempting to write a small engine in C++ using [glfw](http://www.glfw.org/) for window creation. I want to make strong use of raii to come up with an exception-safe architecture and make the engine practically impossible to use in the wrongway.
But i'm currently struggeling with some problems and i feel i like i'm missing something important thus i'm asking here, thank you all in advance!

Suppose i have a basic `raii`-struct called `glfw_context` that calls `glfwInit()` in the `ctor` and `glfwTerminate()` in the `dtor`. it also accepts an `error-callback` and sets it before calling `glfwInit()` but i'll leave such details out since i want to focus on the basic problems.
i also created a class `glfw_window` that requires a `const glfw_context&` in the `ctor` wheras the overloaded `ctor` taking the same kinds of arguments but with a `glfw_context&&` is `deleted`.

the idea behind this was that when the context was an `rvalue` it would only exist during the `ctor` call but `glfwTerminate()` would be called before all windows were properly destroyed (which happens in the `dtor` of the `glfw_window` class).
i implemented `moves` correctly for `glfw_window` whereas the `glfw_context` can neither be copied or moved. but the problems start here:
there is no way that i could stop a user from creating multiple `glfw_context` instances. so i went with a `static` member now since [glfw](http://www.glfw.org/) does not expose something like [glfwIsInit()](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/pull/1054) which solves this issue for the scope of my framework (only the oldest instance would call `glfwTerminate()`) but that still does not protect the user from writing code like this:

```
std::vector< glfw_window > windows;
{
    // introduce explicit scope to demonstrate the problem
    glfw_context context{};
    windows.emplace_back( context, ... );
}
```

in which case the context would still not outlive the window.

is there a nice way of solving this? i do not want to put this in the documentations as a requirement (something like "the context must outlive each window" just does not seem to cut it for me).

my current approach is to use a `std::shared_pointer< glfw_context >` as an argument of `glfw_window`'s `ctor` and store it as a member. however this still does not solve my issues, since i could still `make_shared< glfw_context >()` different contexts and pass them to different windows. and since only the first allocated instance would call `glfwTerminate()` i could still provoce situations where the context was destroyed before all windows.

so what is the right way of approaching that kind of problem? can i build a nice architecture that does works properly here no matter how the user tries to (mis)use it? 
some other thoughts of mine include a `private ctor` in `glfw_context` and a `static` factory-methode combined with the `shared_pointer`-approach but this feels much like a `singleton` and i doubt that this is the best way of approaching things.

Comment: Make constructor private, and create a factory which return the existing shared_ptr or create one.

Comment: but if that `shared_ptr` was static, how would it ever be deleted? of course i could create it in the first call to something like `glfw_context::get_context()` and store it in the `glfw_window` instance and so the `glfw_context` would outlive it, but that static member would still hold a reference, right? what about it's lifetime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use a variant of singleton:

```
class glfw_context;
std::shared_ptr<glfw_context> CreateContext(); // Make it visible at global scope

class glfw_context
{
    glfw_context() {/*Your impl*/}

    glfw_context(const glfw_context&) = delete;
    glfw_context& operator=(const glfw_context&) = delete;
public:
    friend std::shared_ptr<glfw_context> CreateContext()
    {
        static std::weak_ptr<glfw_context> instance;

        auto res = instance.lock();
        if (res == nullptr) {
            res = std::make_shared<glfw_context>();
            instance = res;
        }
        return res;
    }

    /* Your impl */
};
```

Then as long as there is at least one "reference" to your instance, `CreateContext()` returns it, else it creates a new one.
No possibilities to have 2 different instances of `glfw_context`

Comment: thank you @jarod42 ! could you please clarify if there is a difference between making `instance` a `static` member of the `class` or a `static` "member" of `CreateContext()`? Could I hide my implementation and the `static instance` in a .cpp/.cc file or could this yield some troubles? thank you for your solution - i do not have enough rep to upvote it though.

Comment: You can put definition of `CreateContext` in cpp file (but it should still be `friend` (or static method) to be able to call constructor).

Comment: There is subtle differences between `static` member and `static` inside method. When it is first initialized for example. For your case, I expect that both are viable (you won't call `CreateContext` **before** `main`).

Comment: right, those calls shall happen within main only, so this approach will work. one last question regarding your code: is `CreateContext()` intended to be `private` and **not** `static`? _where should it be called?_ i guess my naiive approach would be to have a `public static` member-function called `CreateContext()` with all details hidden inside the cc-file. of course a free `friend` function would also work similar to what you suggested, i'd be very thankful if you could elaborate on the consequences  vs. maybe having the `ctor` of `glfw_context` call that function and store the `shared_ptr`

Comment: to be more precise: having the `glfw_context` storing that `shared_ptr` to an `impl`-class that calls `glfwInit()` and `glfwTerminate()` using `raii`, so it basically hides the fact that there is a `shared_pointer` and a singleton-like concept involved and the implementation could be replaced without changing client-code.

Comment: `CreateContext()` should be either friend function or static public method. You can indeed add a extra layout between this class and the one you want to expose to user (and indeed that layer should have ownership (for ref-count) and so use `shared_ptr` and )